# ASP.Net GridView: Wrong Rendering randomly?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, border

I used much grid views for my own admin overview in my site.

Every GridView has a normal border (1px solid black).

But randomly the border is not set, here an example: http://s2.imgimg.de/uploads/Untitledced993capng.png

The first is the look, the second how it should be. Every time I hit the F5 button, another border disappers, sometimes there are no border, sometimes all borders are correctly there.

Any Ideas?

---

[I've Solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661723/asp-net-gridview-wrong-rendering-randomly/1661857#1661857): It was due to the browser's zoom setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hahaha, found the anser:

I was zommed in!
When I have the grid with Borders, and zoom in, every pageload the borders are different hidden!
The more you zoom in, the more borders are away.

Some kind of funny...

Answer (score 0):

Did you investigate html & css ? It might look like some not closed tag or sometimes it happens that if you close tag like this `<div />` then pages display incorrectly.

Comment: I complete shure no tag is missing.